# While loop rendering unexpected results

Tags: php, pdo, while-loop

I am new to OOP in PHP and I am having some trouble with displaying results the way I would like. My query does gather all the results, The problem is that when trying to add a `<br />` tag for formatting. I am getting my results, then some break tags then results and a different number of break tags and so on. I would expect from the way I coded it every result should have a `<br />` after it but there is a different amount of `<br />` tags after each one. Any advice would be helpful. Here is my code:

```
public function getForumActivity(){
        $user = $this->uid;
        $pdo = $this->db;
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT title FROM board WHERE user=:user");
        $stmt->bindValue(':user',$user,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        try{
                $title = "";
            $stmt->execute();
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                  $title .= $row['title']."<br />";
               }
               return $title;

        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }
```

Comment: can you post the resulting HTML

Comment: Are the any rows that contain an empty `title` value?

Comment: HTML Renders like this: isplaying all results from a query<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />Form validation with jquery<br /><br /><br /><br />Ajax POST Error not sending vars<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />mobile websites and the recent tablets , smartphones<br />Forum Signature<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />PayPal Subscription Integration into your blog<br />IE behaviour<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />How to make a PHP and MySQL like system?

Comment: There are no empty title fields either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that some of your rows in your database have null title value;

Comment: There are not any null values. I know this because my forum system works fine. I coded my site a while back and am now updating old mysql stuff to PDO and procedural code to OO. There are not any null values at all.

Comment: Okay... I am retarded. You were correct. I needed only to query for posts, not replies. The replies had no value in the title field. You guys rock.

Comment: Ok it's a simple mistake that could happen for anyone. Good luck